# Why is it printing out "undefined" first?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this loop that creates List items and inserts that into a `<ol>` element. It works very well, however, the first thing that it prints out is "undefined" inside the `<ol>` (Not as a `<li>` item though), and then the real `<li>` items come afterwards.

`var calculatedPayments` is a number from an `input field` (like 5).

```
 <ol id="month-list" class="list-group"></ol>

 var i;
  var monthsItem;
  for (i=1; i <= calculatedPayments; i++) {
    monthsItem += '<li class="list-group-item"> Månad '+i+':';
    monthList.innerHTML = monthsItem;
    console.log(i);
  }
```

Comment: You're `+=` to the `var monthsItem;` which is `undefined`. Instead - initialise it with an empty string `var monthsItem = '';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use + before = while assigning `<li>` to monthsItem, it's concatenating value of monthsItem (which is undefined obvious ) with your `<li>` snippet. 
Just use simple assignment operator to assign like:

`monthsItem = '<li class="list-group-item"> Månad '+i+':';`

Answer (score 1):

At the first iteration of your loop, your variable `monthsItem` was not yet defined, and therefore, its value was mapped to `undefined` when this line was called:

```
monthsItem += '<li class="list-group-item"> Månad '+i+':';
```

The fix: Initialize `monthsItem` to be an empty string:

```
var monthsItem = "";
```